# How to convert DjVu to PDF without increasing file size?

Tags: pdf, djvu

I am satisfied with the tools I use for annotating/marking up PDF (highlighting and searching for text, mostly), which is why I want to convert my DjVu files to PDF.

But the converters I have used always blows up the file size. And some do not even preserve the text layer.

What tools are available which achieve both

- preservation of text layer
- no explosion in PDF file size
  ?

Comment: Are you using a supported Ubuntu release? Which? Read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting